# Feasibility of sorting a basket of clothes in the real world

Tags: neural-networks, image-recognition

I'm wondering how feasible it is to create a machine that can separate clothing from a basket.

At the most basic level it would distinguish between tops, pants, button downs and socks

Programmatically, I'd image this would require training a neural network to recognize these items, but in real time it becomes exponentially difficult to do this in a small space at a fast rate:

1. pick up an item
2. lay it in such a way that is recognizable
3. deduce whether it is a top, button down, etc.
4. sort it accordingly

If this sounds ridiculous please let me know...

If it is possible :

would this be based on some sort of computer vision?
or only a well trained neural network?

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Peter Abbeel](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/) does work in deep learning for robotics, and one of the projects they've tackled is manipulating clothes. Here's a [video from 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FGVgMsiv1s) of their robot folding laundry (one piece at a time).

There are also companies attempting to market this; seven dreamers makes the [Laundroid](https://laundroid.sevendreamers.com/?lang=en) and [Foldimate](https://www.foldimate.com/) claims that it will start taking pre-orders in 2017.